# How to use dtype to predefine dtypes of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How this dtype works,I am just getting crazy about this thing.

1: first use python's default type: couldn't work, rase error

```
bins = pd.DataFrame(dtype=[str, int, int], columns=["chrom", "start", "end"])
raise error : TypeError: data type not understood
```

2: use numpy's dtype function.It does work, but the result is wrong.

```
bins = pd.DataFrame(dtype=np.dtype("str","int32","int32"), columns=["chrom", "start", "end"])
bins.dtypes
output:
chrom    object
start    object
end      object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first define a `DataFrame` with the column names, and after that change the types with [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) like following:

```
bins = pd.DataFrame(columns=["chrom", "start", "end"])

bins = bins.astype({'chrom':'object',
                    'start':'int64',
                    'end':'int64'})

print(bins.dtypes)
chrom    object
start     int64
end       int64
dtype: object
```

**note**: I used `object` as type to define a *string* column, which is how `text` column is defined in `pandas`

Comment: what if I want category(which is str originally) instead

Comment: `object` is the equivalent of `string` in pandas, see more here: https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html

Comment: thx,it worked,But this is a little complex . how could I use the dtype parameter in the right way

Comment: What is complex about it? Instead of defining it in `dtypes` argument, you define the types with `astype`

Answer (score 0):

The dtype parameter is a dictionary of column names and dtypes together.

So for your case 
    pd.Dataframe(dtype:{‘chron’:str,‘start’:np.Int33,’end’:np.Int32)